# Why this table In-Cell editor, doesnt work?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, crud

I am trying to figure out, how the primefaces in-cell editor works.

For some reason, it does not work. I just see it activating and also i can type, but the values do not change. What is missing?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable id="allSubjects" var="subject" value="#{subjectControllerUpdate.retrieve()}" paginator="true" rows="7" >
            <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{subject.name}" style="width:200px" >
                <p:cellEditor>  
                    <f:facet name="output">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{subject.name}"/>  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <f:facet name="input">  
                        <p:inputText value="#{subject.name}" style="width:100%"/>  
                    </f:facet>  
                </p:cellEditor>  
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{subject.description}" headerText="Description">               
                <p:cellEditor>  
                    <f:facet name="output">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{subject.description}"/>  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <f:facet name="input">  
                        <p:inputText value="#{subject.description}" style="width:100%"/>  
                    </f:facet>  
                </p:cellEditor>    
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{subject.credits}" headerText="Credits" style="width:50px">
                <p:cellEditor>  
                    <f:facet name="output">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{subject.credits}"/>  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <f:facet name="input">  
                        <p:inputText value="#{subject.credits}" style="width:100%"/>  
                    </f:facet>  
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Options" style="width:50px">                   
                <p:rowEditor />
            </p:column>         
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>    

</html>
```

This is the managed bean

```
package controllers;

import crudfacades.SubjectFacade;
import entities.Subject;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("subjectControllerUpdate")
@SessionScoped
public class SubjectControllerUpdate implements Serializable {

    private List<Subject> subjects;
    private Subject currentSubject;
    @EJB
    private SubjectFacade ejbFacade;

    //INITIALIZATION
    public SubjectControllerUpdate() {
        currentSubject = new Subject();
    }

    //RETRIEVE
    public List<Subject> retrieve() {
        return getSubjectFacade().findAll();
    }

    //UPDATE

    //HELP METHODS
    //RETURN THE FACADE FOR DATA MANIPULATION(Best practice)
    private SubjectFacade getSubjectFacade() {
        return ejbFacade;
    }

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
    public Subject getCurrentSubject() {
        return currentSubject;
    }

    public void setCurrentSubject(Subject currentSubject) {
        this.currentSubject = currentSubject;
    }

    public List<Subject> getSubjects() {
        return subjects;
    }

    public void setSubjects(List<Subject> subjects) {
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "values do not change"?

Comment: @BalusC The editor activates itself when i click, but when i click comfirm, the value in the UI is not changed and i see no changes in the database. This is the component i use: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableEditing.jsf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *but when i click comfirm, the value in the UI is not changed*

You've bound the value of the `<p:dataTable>` to `retrieve()` instead of `getSubjects()`. So every single getter call will get the values straight from the DB instead of the model.

> *and i see no changes in the database*

You are not saving anything in the DB.

Fix your controller as follows:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SubjectControllerUpdate implements Serializable {

    private DataModel<Subject> subjects;

    @EJB
    private SubjectFacade ejbFacade;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        subjects = new ListDataModel<Subject>(ejbFacade.findAll());
    }

    public void save() {
        ejbFacade.save(subjects.getRowData());
    }

    public List<Subject> getSubjects() {
        return subjects;
    }

}
```

with

```html
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable value="#{subjectControllerUpdate.subjects}" ...>
        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{subjectControllerUpdate.save}" />
        ...
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Using `DataModel<Subject>` instead of `List<Subject>` is necessary in order to be able to get the current row.

Comment: I understand my mistake, i fixed as you said, but i have a doubt related with the way i call save. 
My form does not have a p:commandButton, it uses `<p:rowEditor />`, How can i trigger the method `save()`?

Comment: As shown in the answer, add a save button which should save all the changes made during row editing.

Comment: Or if you don't want a save button, you could use `<p:ajax event="rowEdit">` inside the data table.

Comment: Yes i dont want to use a button, instead i would prefer to use the little icon that comes with the `<p:rowEditor>`, so i add the ajax tag inside the table, but i don't understand how the method gets triggered. Should i add also `<p:rowEditor action="#subjectControllerUpdate.save}">`?

Comment: I edited the answer to use `<p:ajax event="rowEdit">` instead.